# How to stretch the component to match the width of parent components in Android layout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

Below is the layout I designed.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/login_button_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/login_button_2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/login_button_3" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_5" />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_6" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_9" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_back" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonRow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonChange"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_dhange" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDisable"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/login_button_disable" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that I want to stretch the bottom two buttons, "Change" and "Back", to match the width of the buttons above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use weight on both of them, like this:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/buttonRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonChange"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="@string/login_button_dhange" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDisable"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="@string/login_button_disable" />
```

Comment: If I do that, the bottom buttons will take over the whole width of screen. Is there any way to make "buttonRow" match the width of "digitRow"

Comment: you can set margins from both sides for the linearlayout of those two buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like the code below.
I used a hard coded button width, but you probably want to put this in dimen.xml and reference it. I centered everything with gravity.

I tried this with weights as well, but the re-sizing is funny. As your screen gets wider the buttons get two wide.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:gravity="center_horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="3" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button5"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button6"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button7"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button8"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button9"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/digitRow4"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonClear"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button0"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="0" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Back" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/buttonRow"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonChange"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonDisable"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Disable" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use weight like below. Also use margins to tweak the positions of the buttons.

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/buttonRow"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="10dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="5dp" >

 <Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonChange"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="@string/login_button_dhange" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonDisable"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1.0"
    android:text="@string/login_button_disable" />
```